# RegExp.exec() returns NULL sporadically

Tags: javascript, regex

I am seriously going crazy over this and I've already spent an unproportionate amount of time on trying to figure out what's going on here. So please give me a hand =)

I need to do some RegExp matching of strings in JavaScript. Unfortunately it behaves very strangely. This code:

```
var rx = /(cat|dog)/gi;
var w = new Array("I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.", "I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.");

for (var i in w) {
    var m = null;
    m = rx.exec(w[i]);
    if(m){
        document.writeln("<pre>" + i + "\nINPUT: " + w[i] + "\nMATCHES: " + m.slice(1) + "</pre>");
    }else{
        document.writeln("<pre>" + i + "\n'" + w[i] + "' FAILED.</pre>");
    }
}
```

Returns "cat" and "dog" for the first two elements, as it should be, but then some `exec()`-calls start returning `null`. I don't understand why.

I posted a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpak/Wgnns/3/), where you can run and edit the code.

And so far I've tried this in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: it fails only on a `"I have a cat and a dog too."`, it seems

Comment: exec returns null if a match fails by design, so for some reason it fails to match.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Oh, here it is. Because you're defining your regex global, it matches first `cat`, and on the second pass of the loop `dog`. So, basically you just need to reset your regex (it's internal pointer) as well. Cf. this:

```
var w = new Array("I have a cat and a dog too.", "I have a cat and a dog too.", "I have a cat and a dog too.", "I have a cat and a dog too.");

for (var i in w) {
    var rx = /(cat|dog)/gi;
    var m = null;
    m = rx.exec(w[i]);
    if(m){
        document.writeln("<p>" + i + "<br/>INPUT: " + w[i] + "<br/>MATCHES: " + w[i].length + "</p>");
    }else{
        document.writeln("<p><b>" + i + "<br/>'" + w[i] + "' FAILED.</b><br/>" + w[i].length + "</p>");
    }
    document.writeln(m);
}
```

Comment: Woh– "internal pointer of a regex"? Could you recommend a resource on that one? Thanks!

Comment: Whoa... I've been writing JavaScript intensively for the last 14 years, and `RexExp`s more & more intensively for the last 8 years -- and this blows my mind pretty hard. Would I have a better understanding of this if I was better at Perl?

Comment: I would give you 1000 up votes if I could. That just saved me hours and blows my mind.

Answer (score 95):

The regex object has a property `lastIndex` which is updated when you run `exec`. So when you exec the regex on e.g. "I have a cat and a dog too.", `lastIndex` is set to 12. The next time you run `exec` on the same regex object, it starts looking from index 12. So you have to reset the `lastIndex` property between each run.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It helps a lot by setting `myRe.lastIndex = 0;` for subsequent use.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer because it follows the best practice of reusing the same regex object

Comment: Agree this should be the correct answer. It reuses the same regex object and also explains the internal mechanics. OP should consider changing.

Answer (score 40):

Two things:

1. The mentioned need of **reset** when using the `g` (global) flag. To solve this I recommed simply assign `0` to the `lastIndex` member of the `RegExp` object. This have better performance than destroy-and-recreate.
2. Be careful when **use `in` keyword in order to walk an `Array`** object, because can lead to unexpected results with some libs. Sometimes you should check with somethign like `isNaN(i)`, or if you know it don't have holes, use the classic for loop.

The code can be:

```
var rx = /(cat|dog)/gi;
w = ["I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.", "I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat.","I have a cat and a dog too.", "There once was a dog and a cat."];

for (var i in w)
 if(!isNaN(i))        // Optional, check it is an element if Array could have some odd members.
  {
   var m = null;
   m = rx.exec(w[i]); // Run
   rx.lastIndex = 0;  // Reset
   if(m)
    {
     document.writeln("<pre>" + i + "\nINPUT: " + w[i] + "\nMATCHES: " + m.slice(1) + "</pre>");
    } else {
     document.writeln("<pre>" + i + "\n'" + w[i] + "' FAILED.</pre>");
    }
  }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Setting `rx.lastIndex = 0` is much better than re-creating the RegEx object inside the loop.

Comment: Still it would be better just not use the `g` flag when you don't want it. It makes no sense to create a regex that specifically updates `lastIndex` just to reset it after each execution.

Comment: You may do want to search globally in an item, and then reset and reuse the regex on the next one. I think OP code is just an example to show what does not understand.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem using /g only, and the proposed solution here did not work for me in FireFox 3.6.8.  I got my script working with

```
var myRegex = new RegExp("my string", "g");
```

I'm adding this in case someone else has the same problem I did with the above solution.

Comment: This "bug" was fixed in ES5. Originally, literal regexes were only instantiated once. Therefor it wasn't necessary to store them in a variable. The formerly succinct `while(/a/g.exec(text)) {...}`  has now to be written as `regex = /a/g; while(regex.exec(text)) {...}`. Probably this change broke a lot of code on the web but is way less error-prone. On the other hand, when you want to reset `lastIndex` after each execution, the correct solution has always been just to remove the `g` flag.